# The syntax of the command is incorrect (Batch-file)

Tags: batch-file

I cannot seem to find the syntax error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

In this batch file:

```
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip"
:: CHECK EXIST 7-zip
IF EXIST "7-Zip" (

    :: COMPRESS WITH 7-zip
    CD "7-Zip"
    7z a -t7z C:\Users\%username%\Thunderbird_BKP\Thunderbird_User.7z

    :: TRANSFER_FILES...

) ELSE (

    :: CREATE Log
    CD "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird"
    ECHO "NOT FOUND 7-ZIP >> "C:\Users\%username%\Thunderbird_BKP\log.txt"

    :: TRANSFER_LOG

)
```

Comment: so.. what is the syntax error? in English please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically do not like to support unclear questions, but I suppose it is clear enough for an answer:

```
:: Check if 7-zip exists
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip" (goto :zipit) else (goto :logit)

:zipit
    :: Compress using 7-zip
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip"
    7z a -t7z C:\Users\%username%\Thunderbird_BKP\Thunderbird_User.7z
    :: Transfer Files...

goto :EOF
:logit
    :: Create Log file
    cd "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird"
    echo "7-Zip Not Found!! >> "C:\Users\%username%\Thunderbird_BKP\log.txt"
    :: Transfer Log
```

I have not tested your actual commands because I do not have `7-zip` installed.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!!